# jQuery: running youtube videos in for loop, plays last video

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `jQuery` function as

```
function play_queue_video() {
    var queue_videos = $('.queue_list .view-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < queue_videos.length; i++) {
        console.log('id - ' + queue_videos[i].id);
        play_video(queue_videos[i].id, true);
    }
}
```

If I have `n` videos, it plays the last video, because it just loops and goes to last

**Needed**
- What can I do to make sure each video plays for the duration it is needed to?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps wrapping your   `play_video()`  call in a closure will work for you.  If not I would look deeper into the YouTube API.

```
function play_queue_video() {
        var queue_videos = $('.queue_list .view-item');
        for (var i = 0; i < queue_videos.length; i++) (function (i){
            console.log('id - ' + queue_videos[i].id);
            play_video(queue_videos[i].id, true);
        }(i));
    }
```

Comment: same behavior, I will check the YouTube API now